# RBDMS design for Employees with admin powers in a Company

Tags: database-design, rdbms

We have two Models, `Company` and `Employee`. One Company has Many Employees.

The vast majority of `Employees` do not have any Admin powers, but there may be one or more employees with Admins powers on that Company.

What is the best way of doing this in the DB? I can think of the following two ways, and both have cons and benefits.

1) Indicate the admin status in the Employee table even though this will be false for the majority of Employees. The benefit is not having to do any joins to determine if an Employee has admins.

```
Company
-------
ID

Employee
--------
ID
Company ID
Is Admin
```

2) Create a junction table between Company and Employee, and include only those employees with admin powers. This requires a join everytime we want to determine if an employee has admin powers.

```
Company
-------
ID
Name

Employee
--------
ID
Company ID

AdminEmployee (Is there a better name for this?)
-------------
ID
Company ID
Employee ID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to do something like this is to create `roles` that can be associated with `users`. Below is the minimum you would need:

A `company` table to list all the companies:

```
company
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    name                varchar(255)
    ...
+----+--------------------+
| id | name               |
+----+--------------------+
|  1 | Acme Brick Company |
|  2 | ABC Widgets Inc    |
| .. | .................. |
+----+--------------------+
```

A `role` table to list all the possible roles:

```
role
    id                  unsigned int(P)
    description     varchar(15)

+----+---------------+
| id | description   |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | Administrator |
|  2 | Clerk         |
| .. | ............. |
+----+---------------+
```

A `user` table to hold all the user information for all companies:

```
user
    id          unsigned int(P)
    company_id  unsigned int(F company.id)
    username    varchar(255)
    password    varbinary(255)
    etc.

+----+------------+----------+----------+-----+
| id | company_id | username | password | ... |
+----+------------+----------+----------+-----+
|  1 |          1 | bob      | ******** | ... |
|  2 |          2 | mary     | ******** | ... |
|  3 |          2 | john     | ******** | ... |
| .. | .......... | ........ | ........ | ... |
+----+------------+----------+----------+-----+
```

And finally an associative table to tie users and roles together. In the example data you can see that user `bob` is an `Administrator` at `ACME Brick Company` while user `mary` is both an `Administrator` and a `Clerk` at `ABC Widgets Inc` and user `john` is a `Clerk` at `ABC Widgets Inc`.

```
user_role
    user_id    unsigned int(F user.id)\_(P)
    role_id    unsigned int(F role.id)/

+----+---------+---------+
| id | user_id | role_id |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 |       1 |       2 |
|  2 |       2 |       1 |
|  3 |       2 |       2 |
|  4 |       3 |       2 |
| .. | ....... | ....... |
+----+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Supplementing Benny's answer above.

An important reason for going with this role approach is that a user could then be given many different roles with different permissions.  You then get significantly improved granularity in permissions without a lot of added cost, db-load-wise.  For example, you could have a purchasing clerk and a sales clerk.  Or you could have different sorts of admins, with different areas of power, and employees could be granted one or more permissions.

It also avoids unnecessary NULLs, etc, and the roles can be pulled lazily when you want.  That doesn't mean that the other approaches are necessarily wrong, but they are generally less flexible.

For the other two approaches, usually I would add the flag if I go that way.  Usually that would be helpful when the application is and you simply don't have domain space of multiple roles (for example, I could see doing this for a specific line of business tool with limited applicability).  In theory the separate table is cleaner, but in practice I don't think it is.

Comment: Yep, makes sense. As of now there are only two roles: admin and non-admin, but in the future there well could be more so I might as well prepare for it. I agree with your last paragraph as well.